# Is there a way to pass back the Request.Files in the view model on post (ASP.NET MVC 3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I've successfully removed references to Request.Form in my code, but I haven't seen any ASP.NET MVC 3 support for binding Request.Files to my view model. Would best practice be to just pass the Request.Files object (HttpFileCollectionBase) to whatever method processes my attachments? E.g.,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(StatusViewModel vm)
{
   bool updated = HandleUpdate(Request.Files, vm);
   ...
   return View("Updated");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply declare Action parameters of type HttpPostedFileBase, like so:

```
public ActionResult Method(HttpPostedFileBase fileUploaded)
```

You can bind to arrays of like-named instances, as well.

```
public ActionResult Method(HttpPostedFileBase[] filesUploaded)
```

and, HttpPostedFileBase can be a member of your view model.

```
public class MyModel{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUploaded{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I tried adding an HttpPostedFileBase to my view model, but I seem to be missing the glue that ties it to the Request object's file. (Request.Files has content, which it is not putting into my object.)

Comment: The field has to be properly named to match the field name, just like any other form field.